# How can I duplicate an object with independent meshes?

Tags: python, mesh, objects

I am trying to duplicate a mesh object using python. After duplication I try to change the duplicated object's mesh, but the original object's mesh also changes.

Seem like both objects have the same mesh. How can I also duplicate the mesh?

Here is some Code:

```
>>> obj1 = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
>>> obj2 = obj1.copy()
>>> bpy.context.collection.objects.link(obj2)
>>> obj1.location = Vector((3,0,0))
>>> obj2.animation_data_clear()
>>> ve = obj2.data.vertices[0]
>>> ve.co = ve.co*2
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should copy object data.

```
obj1 = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
data = obj1.data.copy()
obj2 = obj1.copy()
obj2.data = data
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(obj2)
obj1.location = Vector((3,0,0))
obj2.animation_data_clear()
ve = obj2.data.vertices[0]
ve.co = ve.co*2
```

Comment: That works for the mesh. Now the modifiers and vertex groups get lost, when copying. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: Thank you for the help!